# Extract RTF Data from Informix Table with DBUNIT

Tags: java, xml, jaxb, rtf, dbunit

I need to extract tables from my informix instance that contain RTF document data.

Most of the content seems to conform. The content begins with

```
{\rtf1\ansi\ansicpg1252\uc1\deff0\deflang1033\defl ...
```

But some other content contains special characters (I think they come from a tool like Word ...). When extracting DBUNIT, these characters are put in the XML and corrupted it.

Have you ever encountered this problem and if so, have you found a workaround?

Answer (score 1):

XML effectively is plain text so, for non-plain-text data, requires a little extra notation.  Often this is CDATA or base64 notation as required for the "special" data.

Depending on the database column definition type, update the XML mapping to use CDATA or binary.

CDATA:

```
   <![CDATA[
      the rtf text
   ]] >
```

Binary format is a blob field.  dbUnit supports that as documented here: http://dbunit.sourceforge.net/datatypes.html#blob

Comment: Thank you for your help. I implemented the CDATA sectin well because indeed it is better.

However, in some of my RTF I have illegal XML characters (eg 0x11) and the XML is still badly formatted.

I understand that there is no other choice but to delete them?

Comment: Try XML 1.1 which allows many more characters that were illegal in XML 1.0.

Comment: I don't now how i can force DBUNIT to create XML in version 1.1 because org.dbunit.util.xml.XmlWriter clas only use 1.0 (It's in the code of the class). 

In my case, there is Unicode char (eg : 0x11) and I try with and without CDATA tag on my xml element but it doesn't change anything : the spring batch reader (staxEventItemReader) can read this object. Any tips ?

Comment: If you manually change the value to 1.1, does it work or error?

Comment: I didn' try because I think XmlWriter use v1.0 for construct XML file. But i have applied an alternative solution, I check all char of rtf data and if there any xml invalid char, i skip it. It's not the best solution but I can accept this lost data in my traitement. Thanks for all your support

Comment: Agreed, not the best solution but works.  I strongly encourage you to create a feature request at https://sourceforge.net/p/dbunit/feature-requests/ with an attached sample data file containing problematic characters.  Best if you make a test that shows the problem (attach file, git patch, or git merge request) so someone can run it and fix sometime.  If you can include a dbUnit change that supports (whether to support XML 1.1 or other), that's the best yet and will enabling easily adding to dbUnit.